# How do you get rid of the blank gap left after cropping an image in opencv c++?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am writing a program to analyze pictures and crop them around an object in the picture. The program crops the images well, but it leaves a weird gap on the side.

I copied the code from the approved answer on this question:
[Opencv c++ detect and crop white region on image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344380/opencv-c-detect-and-crop-white-region-on-image)

The image I start with looks like this on a larger canvas. I get this result, but I want to get rid of the extra white space on the left side in order to crop super close to the phone case. It can be seen better if you open the image in a new tab.

Please help. I am using opencv and c++ in Visual Studio 2015.

[image: Result]

Comment: Hard to see if your browser has a white background. Although if you click on the image chrome shows it on a black background.

Comment: You are not clear. Did you copy the code without modifying it to get rid off the white background? It detects black background - won't work for white if unchanged.

Comment: try changing this line: if(in.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) != cv::Vec3b(0,0,0)) to this line: if(in.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) != cv::Vec3b(255,255,255)) if your background is pure white.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I did change that line like @Micka mentioned so that it has Vec3b(255,255,255). The background is pure white, but as drescherjm mentioned opening the image in a new tab shows that the image has a large white bar on the side. That is the result after running the programming. However, I want the bar to be cropped away too.

Comment: is the image you provided a crop of the original or is it magnified?

Comment: @zteffi It is a crop of the original image. The original image was a picture of the case in the center of a white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This picture is not correctly cropped because of [salt-and-pepper noise](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Salt-and-pepper_noise). To get rid of it you'd use [median blur](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=medianblur#medianblur). You can use blurred image to fill nonBlackList and use this list to correctly crop original image. Since it appears the image was slightly magnified after the noise appeared, you should probably try aperture size at least 5 to get rid of it completly.

```
cv::Mat in = cv::imread("CropWhite.jpg");
cv::Mat blurred;
cv::medianBlur(in, blurred, 5);
```

...

```
if(blurred.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) != cv::Vec3b(255,255,255))
{
    nonBlackList.push_back(cv::Point(i,j));
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much @zteffi! The image is cropped exactly how I asked! Is there a method that I can use to crop the picture the same way but leave a margin on all sides? (Maybe 50px around all edges?)

Comment: bb is a rectangle, which you can modify. bb.x -=50; bb.width += 100 and so on.